# Installing Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu while keeping Windows 10 as isolated as possible

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, grub

### TLDR;

I want to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu, while treating Windows as the secondary OS similarly to how bootcamp does with macOS, but I'm not sure all what I have to do in the Windows side of things to achieve that.

### Some Background

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on an isolated drive in my system currently running Ubuntu. I've previously dual booted Windows 7 alongside various Debian distros, but once Windows 7 reached end of support, that's the last that I've worked with Windows. I've helped others dual boot/install linux on Windows 10 systems before, and it feels like Windows 10 takes control over parts of the boot behavior outside of the BIOS/UEFI settings where I'd assume to have control over that. My goal is to only boot occasionally into Windows 10 to play online multiplayer games with aggressive anti-cheat that doesn't allow me to use wine/proton/a vm. My problem is I don't know what I need to be watching out for with Windows 10, since I've never really dove into what processes it takes control of.

### My Goals

- Install Windows 10 onto a standalone drive on a system already running Ubuntu
- Keep that Windows 10 install from getting any control over the boot process at any point

### My Current Plan

- Install Windows 10 to the SSD
- Use a live usb to boot and reconfigure grub (this part I'm not worried about)
- Go into my UEFI and disable secure and fast boot (My machine still has a legacy BIOS, but if I chose to use one of my systems with UEFI, I'd need to do this).
- Disable hibernation in Windows 10

### Some Issues I anticipate running into

- Even though I've disabled secure and fast boot on systems, it feels like Windows still likes to just boot into itself ignoring the BIOS/UEFI level.
- A Windows 10 update reverting my changes to then take control over parts of the boot process again. (I'm not sure if this can actually happen, or if I'm just assuming stories I've read)

### Pipe Dreams

- An ideal solution to this would be to install Windows 10 to a drive in an enclosure and boot from either USB/eSATA, but I feel as if this has it's own litany of workarounds since the concept of a live Windows install doesn't appear to exist.

Is disabling the secure and fast boot settings in the UEFI settings and hibernation directly in Windows 10 sufficient to make sure when I restart Windows 10, I boot into grub, or am I missing anything here?

Is the solution of installing to a drive interfacing via USB/eSATA a more viable option that I think it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install both systems in UEFI boot mode.

Windows installed in UEFI mode doesn't interfere with other OSes. Worst-case scenario is Windows will change boot order during upgrade, you can fix this in UEFI setup in 30 seconds without any extra resources.

Whether it's installed on a separate disk or not is irrelevant, installing to the same disk is safe.

Comment: So as long as I have grub properly configured, rebooting out of Windows 10 would bring back to grub correct? It won't just reboot directly to Windows? I know I've taken this approach before when installing Mint alongside Windows 10 from someone, but I sometimes ran into an issue where booting into Windows, would only reboot into Windows, no grub screen, even with fast boot turned off in UEFI. Is this not an issue I should be anticipating?

Comment: You could have this issue if you were using Windows' bootmgr as first stage loader and fast startup would be enabled in Windows, but this setup is highly unusual and not recommended unless you want Windows to be your primary OS. If GRUB (or whatever you use to boot Linux) is your primary loader, this issue can't occur because no Windows code executes until you choose it.

Comment: That clears up exactly what I was confused about. Thanks!